# Error: It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pycharm

I am running Mac OS 10.10.5. and Python 3 and XCode 7.2.1. I installed SciKit-Learn and all of its dependencies with pip (PyCharm) and I am getting this error when I try to use the package. I tried it on another computer also running 10.10.5 and didn't get the error. Here is the full error message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Users/jonathankogan/PycharmProjects/Test/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ._check_build import check_build
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__check_build)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonathankogan/PycharmProjects/Test/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
    %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__check_build)
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
__init__.py               __pycache__               _check_build.cpython-35m-darwin.so
setup.py
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

Comment: Can you provide more code, so we can get a clue what code causes the exception?

Comment: @kabaehr The error seems to be occuring in the line `from sklearn import datasets`.

Comment: I have not much knowledge of python and just reviewed your task, so that python expierenced users has a change to answer your question. E.g. please provide more information and code snippets about how you installed the plugin, how you imported the plugin...